# re-mount React child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Here I've initialized my application:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Now I need for all components in tree to call componentDidMount again because I want for all these components in tree to call api requests again.

I've done it like this:

```
const appKey = 0;

ReactDOM.render(
    <App key={appKey} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And each time I need for components to call componentDidMount again I add 1 to appKey and call ReactDOM.render again. It works. But maybe there is another way of doing this without using key attribute?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.. what are you trying to accomplish? I mean, why do you need to re-render everything?

Comment: @BravoZulu, 
 
I'm creating electron.js application. User can open project in my application and work with this project in my application. Then he can open another project. In each component in componentDidMount method I want to get data from API. When the user opened first project componentDidMount was triggered. But when user opens new project I want componentDidMount to be triggered again in each component to get data from API for project.

Comment: You could achieve this in lots of ways. For instance you could toggle a flag that is passed to your components e.g refetchData and then handle this in componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate. When all this is done set the flag to false again. Trying to force all components to remount seems very wasteful.